# FMI co-simulation run time error in Simulink

Tags: simulink, fmi

At first I have exported a simulink model to FMU in Simulink and then imported this FMU also in the Simulink using FMU import block and later when I tried to run the simulation the following error shows up, could anyone please help me out with this?

```
Log from FMU: [category:logStatusError, status:fmi2Error] Simulation terminated due to error(s) at start time.
Log from FMU: [category:logStatusError, status:fmi2Error] fmi2ExitInitializationMode: FMU encountered runtime error during simulation.
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: It seems the function fmi2ExitInitializationMode() returns fmi2Error due to issues happened at the slave side. Have you tried to run the Simulink model in a clean, standalone MATLAB to see if you get compilation or runtime errors? For example, you may have unsaved model changes, missing base workspace variables, or may have forgotten to include mat file or submodel file into the Simulink project before exporting to FMU.